# Running USB chapter 9 tests using gadgetfs fails

Tags: android, linux, usb

I am trying to run USB compliance tests on Android gadget 
which is using GadgetFs. The tests are failing from the
very 2nd test. When I tried searching around I found

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg99469.html

But the thread describes about FunctionFS which is quite
different than GadgetFS. However both of them uses same
composite.c file which is USB composite driver.

I found the exact issue described in above post with my 
hardware too in which SET_CONFIGURATION request is failing
because of during setting configuration to 0 composite driver
tries to reset USB configuration which disconnects USB gadget
which seems wrong.

I would like ask here, Is there any known issue? Or is there
anybody who tried running chapter 9 tests on Android gadget using
GadgetFS functionality could give some tips?

Comment: Hi!Did you get anywhere with your problem? May I ask what your maximum transfer speeds are with gadgetfs?